# How to fill ProgID after creation ATL COM object. ProgID importance

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, atl, rgs

I'm trying to create com object using C++ ATL. In add ATL Simple Object wizard I forgot to fill ProgID field. Is it possible to add ProgID later? I found that it is located in *.rgs file. Is it safe to edit this file? If yes, how to deal with UI that are also required in definition syntax in this case?
  As I understod ProgID  is important when you want to create COM object for example using command CreateObject in VB. What are other methods to create com object with late binding when ProgId is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's safe to edit the .rgs file. It's just a registry script - defining where the ProgID is going to be inserted into the registry. (When using C++ in Visual Studio, it seems to me that they don't seem to have as many automatically-generated files that you shouldn't edit. The ones that are generated are usually labelled. (Like the stubs and headers that are generated from .idl files.))

All the wizards are doing is automatically filling in some of the files that you would normally need to do by hand. Knowing what gets put where is really useful, so, if you've already tracked down this bit, it sounds like you're on the right track.